# tar: распаковать архив без замены файлов

Tags: linux, tar, archive

Здравствуйте!
Есть архив запакованный при помощи tar -сpvf который необходимо распаковать в директорию которая уже содержит часть файлов из архива. Вопрос: Как распаковать его **без замены** файлов, которые уже есть в директории?

Comment: Опция называется вполне очевидно - `--keep-old-files`. [Больше опций](http://askubuntu.com/a/128500/548598)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

```
man tar 

-k, --keep-old-files
       don't replace existing files when extracting,
```

Answer (score 5):

Судя по [man tar](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=tar&category=1), вам нужен ключ `-k(--keep-old-files)`

> -k, --keep-old-files
>   сохраняет существующие файлы и не перекрывает их при извлечении объектов архива

Т.е. вызов будет

```bash
tar xfkv archive.tar /path/to/extract/
```

Скрипт для проверки:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# читаем справку
#man tar
# Создаем директорию для теста
mkdir tmp
mkdir tmp/dir
# наполняем файлами
touch tmp/file0.txt
touch tmp/file1.txt
touch tmp/dir/file0.txt
# создаем архив
tar cf tmp.tar tmp
# удалим часть файлов
rm tmp/file0.txt
# распакуем без замены
tar xfkv tmp.tar
```